# Listening to signalStrength when phone sleeps

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, wakelock, telephonymanager

i've developed a broadcastreceiver that listen to the phone signal strength
declared in the manifest in this way

```
<receiver android:name="it.cazzeggio.android.PhoneStateListener" >
   <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIG_STR" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

the java code is

```
public class PhoneStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e(PhoneStateListener.class.getSimpleName(), new Date().toString());
    try{
       TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
          context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

       //...some checks to be sure that is a gsm-event..

       GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();
       foundCells.add(0,new String[] {
           telephony.getNetworkOperator() + "_" + location.getLac() + "_" + 
               location.getCid() , ""+(bundle.getInt("GsmSignalStrength")+1)});
       if(!foundCells.isEmpty())
          Functions.CellHistory.addHistory(foundCells);
    }catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(PhoneStateListener.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

if the screen is on everything is ok, but when the phone go in sleep mode
my receiver stops working (=no event is dispatched to method onReceive)

I've tryed registering the receiver as service or using the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK without results (i'm a newbie). Any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the code of your BroadcastReceiver class? Include it here.

Comment: can you publish your PhoneStateListener class code

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, googling in the net i've found that is an unresolved android issue:
just to save battery, when the screen is off, the phone stops updating all listeners
about the signal strengths. So for the moment i give up.

I just make a stupid workaround to get at least the cell-id the phone is connected to:
in the manifest i define the service

```
<service android:name="it.cazzeggio.android.util.OffScreenPhoneListener"/>
```

the service will be started in the onCreate method of my main activity when the app starts

```
startService(new Intent(this, OffScreenPhoneListener.class));
```

in the class OffScreenPhoneListener the 'onCreate' method starts
a timer to repeat periodically a check on the phone cell tower

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
   OffScreenPhoneListener.class.getSimpleName());
if(!wakeLock.isHeld())
   wakeLock.acquire();
timer=new Timer();
timer.schedule(new myTimerTask(), DELAY, DELAY);
```

myTimerTask extends TimerTask and has in its method:

```
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
   getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();
//Adding to my history the following infos:
//  telephony.getNetworkOperator()
//  location.getLac()
//  location.getCid()
```

the onDestroy method cleans all the stuff i made:

```
super.onDestroy();
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
if(wakeLock!=null && wakeLock.isHeld())
  wakeLock.release();
```

Thanks anyway for your attention.